# macOS Show Preview Panel in File Chooser Dialogs

Tags: macos, finder, preview

In **Finder**, I have the option of seeing a **Preview Panel**. This shows file details and image thumbnails when I select a file in the Finder, and is very useful.

I also want to see the Preview Panel in **file chooser dialog windows**. For example, if I am working in Google Chrome, and I want to upload an image to some web page, and I click on an Upload button in the page, a file chooser dialog window appears. This file chooser looks just like Finder, but there does not seem to be an option to show the Preview Panel. This is inconvenient because I can't see which image is which in the chooser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose Column View in file dialogs, you should see the preview pane.

Quick Look should also work in file dialogs, by pressing Space, and image files in Icon View should show an icon of their content.

Comment: Column View, that works, thanks!